# Copy resource/data dependencies of libraries to executables with CMake

Tags: cmake

Consider the following project structure

```
root/
  Library1/
    ... .cpp & .h files ...
    resources/
      textures/...
      strings/...
  Library2/
    ... .cpp & .h files ...
    resources/
      html/...
  ...Other Libraries.../...
  Product1/
    main.cpp
  Product2.cpp
    main.cpp
  ...Other Products.../...
```

Let say `Product1` depends on `Library1` then in order for `product1.exe` to function it must be located in a folder containing a `resources` folder which has all the resources located in the `root/Library1/resources`.This would even hold if `Product1` depends on `LibraryX` which depends on `Library1`.

**Q:** How would I ensure in CMake that if an executable depends an a library that its resources are copied?

Worth noting:

- I would **like, if possible,** to avoid having `Product1` depend on some target like `COPY_LIBRARY1_RESOURCES` as `Library1` might not be a direct dependency of `Product1` and could thus be easily missed or forgotten.
- It would be best if this copying is only done for executable targets and not in between libraries.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trail and error this is the solution I came up with.

A basic project structure:

[image: Image showing a basic project structure]

**Interface**

`(root)/Libraries/Lib1/CmakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library( Lib1 Lib1.h Lib1.cpp )

set( 
    Lib1_Resource_List 
        ./resources/html/Example.html
        ./resources/images/Example.png
)

copy_files_command( ${Lib1_Resource_List} )

add_resource_target( Lib1_Resources Lib1 )
add_resources( Lib1_Resources ${Lib1_Resource_List} )
```

Here there are 3 custom function

- `copy_files_command` a utility function which creates custom commands which copy files from `CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR` to `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` whilst preserving local paths
- `add_resource_target` adds a target responsible for managing the resources of another target and configures necessary dependencies and properties
- `add_resources` which add resources to a resource target. **important**: if your resources are generated theses should be the local paths of the generated files not the files from which they were generated.

`(root)/Products/App1/CmakeLists.txt`

```
add_executable( App1 main.cpp )

target_link_libraries( App1 Lib1 )

collect_resources( App1 )
```

Here there is only one new function `collect_resources` which will copy the resources from the targets dependencies post build and place them next to the executable.

in the top level cmake we add 2 lines to include the needed functions

```
include( "resources.cmake" )
include( "utils.cmake" )
```

**Important** this solution only works for `cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)`

**Implementation**

`utils.cmake`

```
### Copies files from CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR to CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR as is preserving local paths
function( copy_files_command )
    foreach( resource ${ARGN} )
        cmake_path(GET resource PARENT_PATH resource_dir) ### Get the base path of a local file
        add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT
                ${resource}
            DEPENDS
                "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${resource}"
            COMMAND
                ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${resource_dir} ### ensure destination actually exists
            COMMAND
                ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/${resource}" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/${resource}" ### copy
        )
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

`resources.cmake`

```
### Append a list of values to a property of a target
function( append_properties target property )
    set( suffix ${ARGN} )
    get_target_property(existing_elements ${target} ${property} )
    if( existing_elements )
        list( PREPEND suffix ${existing_resources} )
    endif()
    set_target_properties( ${target} PROPERTIES ${property} "${suffix}" )
endfunction()

### Registers a new resource target
function( add_resource_target target_name target_reference )
    add_library( ${target_name} INTERFACE )  ### Create it as an interface library
    append_properties( ${target_reference} RESOURCE_TARGETS ${target_name} ) ### Associate the resource target with the original target
    add_dependencies( ${target_reference} ${target_name} ) ### Make the original target depend on the resource target
endfunction()

### Add resources ( in the build directory not the source directory ) to a resource target
### These must be local to CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR
function(add_resources resource_target)
    set( resources_structure ${ARGN} )
    set( resources_absolute ${ARGN} )
    list( TRANSFORM resources_absolute PREPEND "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/" )
    ### Save both local and global path
    append_properties( ${resource_target} TARGET_RESOURCES_STRUCTURE ${resources_structure} )
    append_properties( ${resource_target} TARGET_RESOURCES_ABSOLUTE ${resources_absolute} )
    ### add the resources as dependencies to the resource target
    target_sources( ${resource_target} PUBLIC ${resources_absolute} )
endfunction()

### Get the list of directly dependent resource targets
macro(get_resource_targets target_name out_list_0)
    if(TARGET ${target_name})
        get_target_property(resource_targets ${target_name} RESOURCE_TARGETS)
        if( resource_targets )
            list( APPEND ${out_list_0} ${resource_targets} )
        endif()
    endif()
endmacro()

### Get the list of ALL dependent resource targets
macro(get_resource_targets_recursive target_name out_list_1)
    if(TARGET ${target_name})
        get_resource_targets( ${target_name} ${out_list_1} )
        get_target_property(target_dependencies ${target_name} INTERFACE_LINK_LIBRARIES)
        
        if( target_dependencies )
            foreach(dep ${target_dependencies})
                get_resource_targets_recursive( ${dep} ${out_list_1} )
            endforeach()
        endif()
    endif()
endmacro()

### Generate post build commands for copying resource dependences to $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>
function( collect_resources target )
    set( needed_resource_targets "" )
    get_resource_targets_recursive( ${target} needed_resource_targets )

    ### Create a custom target so the copy is always performed
    add_custom_target( "${target}_COPY_RESOURCES" COMMAND "echo" "Copying Files..." ) #Command seems necesary here
    add_dependencies( ${target} "${target}_COPY_RESOURCES" )

    foreach( resource_target ${needed_resource_targets} ) ### For each resource target
        # Fetch the needed resources
        get_target_property(resources_structure ${resource_target} TARGET_RESOURCES_STRUCTURE )
        get_target_property(resources_absolute ${resource_target} TARGET_RESOURCES_ABSOLUTE )

        ### Make copy target depend on the resource_target
        add_dependencies( "${target}_COPY_RESOURCES" ${resource_target} )

        foreach( resource_structure resource_absolute IN ZIP_LISTS resources_structure resources_absolute )
            cmake_path(GET resource_structure PARENT_PATH resource_dir)
            add_custom_command(
                TARGET "${target}_COPY_RESOURCES"
                POST_BUILD
                COMMAND
                    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E make_directory "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>/${resource_dir}"
                COMMAND
                    ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy "${resource_absolute}" "$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>/${resource_structure}"
                COMMENT
                    "Copying from: ${resource_absolute} to: $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${target}>/${resource_structure}"
            )
        endforeach()
    endforeach()
endfunction()
```

Summary: It registers the resources as properties to the targets and then recursively searches all the dependencies of a target to find those resources